# Get real-time I/O of any storage devices in Windows

Tags: windows-7, usb, hard-disk

Currently, Windows 7 have Resource Monitor to measure storage devices (e.g. HDD, USB Thumb drives, etc). However, it does not display real-time I/O speed. Resource Monitor only shown the Active Time (%).

So, are there any software that is portable and allow user to view the real-time I/O speed (in Mbps) of any storage devices for Windows 7?